# Average distance from one point to several others - any way to avoid sqrt?

Tags: c++, calculation, square-root, pythagorean

For some mesh transformation, I do have to compute the average distance between each point to several other points around it.

That can be done using the Pythagorean theorem but using it fully is quite slow due to the square root operations. Often when computing and comparing distances, the square-root is omitted for speed reasons.
However in my case I require an average and unfortunately without square rooting every single computing distance before computing the average, the result is drastically skewed so far.

Is there a way to compute the average distance with just N square roots in total (like one per point), instead of N * N of those?

Edit: Am aware that I can reduce computations by caching already computed distances and perhaps use a lookup-table for the square roots (since my values are not very large and the result may be rounded to an int), but a mathematical improvement would still be better.

Comment: Has profiling shown that computing the square root is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that the square root is limiting your performance; if so, you could approximate the result by not considering all other points but drawing random ones.